# how to ignore already checked checkboxes in vb.net / asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If i have 3 asp.net checkboxes in my asp.net webform namely : CheckBox1, Checkbox2, Checkbox3 and a textbox namely textbox1

```
If Checkbox1.text ="1"
Checkbox2.text ="2"
Checkbox3.text ="3"
```

**I WANT :**

if checkbox1 is already checked ... if checkbox is remain checked and even after i check checkbox2 and checkbox3 then the output in textbox would be 2,3 ..... by ignoring already checked checkbox text ...

**LOGIC I WANT :** Ignore already check checkboxes and insert recent checkbox text to textbox1 as comma seperated string ...

How to do that ?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want. Can you post examples of what output you want for different check states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Onpageload
bool[] ignorecheckboxes = new bool[2]; //2 should be the number of textboxes

if (checkbox1.Checked = true)
{
ignorecheckboxes[0] = false;
}
if (checkbox2.Checked = true)
{
ignorecheckboxes[1] = false;
}

//When you check again
bool[] checkboxes = new bool[2]; 

if (checkbox1.Checked = true)
{
checkboxes[0] = true;
}
if (checkbox2.Checked = true)
{
checkboxes[1] = true;
}

if (ignorecheckboxes[0] == false)
{
checkboxes[0] = false;
}
if (ignorecheckboxes[1] == false)
{
checkboxes[1] = false;
}
//Everything still true in the checkboxes array is what you want.
```

I would have added another comment, but the code was too long.

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes should not uncheck themselves when they are checked. Radiobuttons are what do that.

I am not sure if that answered your question, but I could not understand it completely. Please post part of your code so we can see what you mean.

Comment: The simple logic is that .... if checkbox1 or checkbox2 or checkbox3 whatever the checkboxes is already checked on page load say if checkbox2 is checked already on page load /./// then when i check checkbox1 and then checkbox3 then in textbox1 the out put would be ..1,3 which igore the already checked checkbox (checkbox2)

Comment: Then you would have to write a function to detect all checkboxes that are checked on load and then ignore them again when u check the 2nd time. 

I would create an array of booleans. Element 0 would be checkbox1, Element 1 would be checkbox2, etc. Make them false if you do not want to check them the 2nd time.

Comment: Can anybody develop that for me ? in vb.net ? I would be very thankful to you ?